# Python: scipy odeint plot not smooth

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, odeint

I'm working on a piece of code which plots the expansion of the universe (using the Friedmann equation) and I need smooth plots but I am getting plots that have a kink in them. I think maybe this is to do with the steps I use in the np.linspace function (could be in the integration) but the kink is still visible when I fiddle about to smooth it. My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint

t_0 = 0.0004
a_0 = 0.001
omega_m = 0.3089
omega_r = 0
omega_lambda = 0.6911
omega_k = 1 - omega_lambda - omega_m - omega_r
H_0 = 1./13.7

def Friedmann(a, t):
    dadt = H_0 * (((omega_m) * a**(-1)) + ((omega_r) * a**(-2)) + ((omega_lambda) * a**2) + (omega_k))**(1./2.)
    return dadt

t = np.linspace(t_0,40)
a = odeint(Friedmann, a_0, t)
a = np.array(a).flatten()

plt.plot(t,a,'b')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Scale factor')
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis([0,40,0,6])
plt.show()
```

The plot I get is as follows

[image: generated plot]

The kink is visible in the bottom left corner of the plot. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to use more points? E.g. 200 points instead of 50? `t = np.linspace(t_0,40, 200)`

Comment: Instead of `linspace()` you may want to add more points where the derivative changes more abruptly.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that's sorted it out completely, thank you